# QGIS 3.24.1 - Problem Plugin NTv2 Datum Transformations - A failure in the SSL library occurred (_ssl.c:1129)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, ntv2-transformation

I'm trying to use the NTV2 Datum Transformations Plugin, but I'm not able to process it without errors (I'm using Win10). I am trying to use the transformation "[AT] Direct and inverse Vector Transformation".
I get this error:

A failure in the SSL library occurred (_ssl.c:1129)

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

I have installed the same software versions on another computer, everything ok there but it doesn't work on my main computer.

Here the error Code in Text Format:

```
urllib.error.URLError: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1253, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1008, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 948, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1422, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: A failure in the SSL library occurred (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalAlgorithmDialog.py", line 143, in parametersHaveChanged
    commands = self.algorithm().getConsoleCommands(parameters, context, feedback, executing=False)
  File "C:\Users/Alex/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ntv2_transformations\VectorAT_MGIETRS89DirInv.py", line 169, in getConsoleCommands
    urlretrieve('http://www.naturalgis.pt/downloads/ntv2grids/at/AT_GIS_GRID.gsb', gridFile)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 239, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 555, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 747, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: 


Python-Version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS-Version: 3.24.1-Tisler Tisler, 5709b824 

Python-Pfad:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.24.1\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.24.1\bin
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\GDAL-3.4.1-py3.9-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Error messages and code should be posted as text, not as a screenshot. It is very difficult to read for some users and impossible for screen readers, and google. Please take the [tour] to see how this site works.

Comment: I updated my post. I have added the error code in text format.

Comment: What if you try to check the *'Use Proxy for Web Access'* in the `Settings > Options > Network`

Comment: Currently I use the setting "Default Proxy". Which setting should be set in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able o find the reason, so I had to allow unverified ssl with the following code
`import ssl ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context` Afterwards the plugin was executed without errors.